# Socket left in TIME_WAIT after file transfer via netcat

Tags: linux, bash

Using [Copying by NetCat](http://www.screenage.de/blog/2007/12/30/using-netcat-and-tar-for-network-file-transfer) I am trying to copy files throught network by *NetCat*. From console it work pretty well. First I run listening netcat on the destination machine and after I run sending on source machine.

The problem is it's doen't work from script from the source machine:

> ssh -f user@$desthost 'nc -l 1234 | tar xvf - > /dev/null &' #listening on destination host
>
> tar cv /tmp/file | nc $desthost 1234 #sending to destination host

I saw that after running port 1234 is still was open and status of the socket was TIME_WAIT.

If you know what's the problem, please, help me out.

And by the way, after copying how can I validate that the content is identical?

Thanks!

Addendum:

I found one very strange thing, the same implementation with *screen* on destination work works, but not stable, sometimes it doesn't copy a file.

> ssh  user@$desthost screen -dm -S test 'nc -l 1234 | tar xvf - ' #listening on destination host

Maybe there is an issue with timeout?

Comment: Do you know that ssh already offers a file transfer service called scp ?

Comment: @Ben, Thank you for the comment, I am interested in netcat because of it's speed

Comment: @com you can decide that speed is your first priority, or you can decide that features (like success validation, resuming partial transfers, etc) is your priority. If you care about things in the latter set, I'd consider rsync (and, if you care about speed more than authentication or security, rsync over raw socket instead of rsync over ssh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need netcat for that:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/

You just need a single ssh connection.

Afterwards use md5sum to compare the files. It's smart to also check the filesize first..

Comment: I am interested in netcat because of it's speed, thanks for md5sum, does it work for directories?

Comment: @com don't use md5sum on the directory, use it on the intermediate tar file. You can tee through md5sum (and its output to stderr) on either end of the pipeline.